# i want to match one cell to another on another sheet the have it pull data from a particular row

Tags: excel

I am trying to match Data from one sheet to another in such away that it first finds the name in sheet 2 that matches column A then pulls data from a specific line under that matched name
Using this code `=LOOKUP(A6,Sheet2!B2:D2,Sheet2!B6:D6)` i can get it to look on sheet 2 and find for example elephant but i cant bet it to then cross reference that name and pull data from sheet 2 on the corresponding line For example i want it to confirm on sheet 2 that it is looking at Elephant (efficiency - Elephant)  and then look at line length of cape and pull data from the corresponding cell. 
[image]

So I'm looking to first confirm that on sheet one it confirms on sheet to it is using elephant and then i would like it to go to Row "length of cape and grab information from corresponding column that is elephant

I hope this makes sense as i am still learning Excel

Answer (score 0):

[Use Match to find rows and columns, then index to use the match results.
Modify these to suit your needs as I don't understand what you want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ATBw.png)
        Row(vertical list)             Column(horizontal list)
=match(elephant,list of animals,0) =match(metrics,metrics list,0)

=index(data table,match result cell for row,match result cell for column)

Comment: i want to reference sheet 1 name (elephant)  then look on sheet 2 and find that name, then look for certain words. In this case  "length of cape" then by matching the name from sheet 1 and the row "Length of Cape" respond with the intersecting cell on sheet 1 this is the code i am using  but it only confirms the name  doesnt allow for Excel to find row i have to tell it what row to pull the data from. if the info moved lines it doesnt work.  =IFERROR(LOOKUP(A7,SHEET2!B2:P2,SHEET2!B10:P10),"") also i cant get this to work using Vlookup instead of lookup

Comment: using Elephant as the reference on sheet1 "LOOKUP(A3" find this word on sheet2 "SHEET2!C2:E2" then go to row containing words (length of cape) "SHEET2!C5:E5" and now go down and across and show results from intersecting cell on sheet 2 on sheet 1 Elephant being cell A3  this is code im using . =IFERROR(LOOKUP(A3,SHEET2!C2:E2,SHEET2!C5:E5),"") as you can see i am using C5:E5 to specify row to look on.  i need it to find the row its self using the keyword Length of cape.